# What are windows message 0x02c8 and 0x02c9?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-messages

I have a winforms app that runs on a PC connected to an industrial machine. There are multiple computers connected trough a display channel switching device and a USB input switching device. This means that the computer starts without a screen or any input devices connected.

The problem we have is with a hosted WPF component. This component is initialised before a touch device is connected. After a touch device is connected everything can be controlled except the WPF component (it responds to a normal mouse).

As such the solution seems simple, reinitialize the WPF component after the touch device is connected. So we tried overriding the `WndProc` method like below. Using the `WindowsMessage` enum from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums.WindowsMessages).

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine($"#{currentTime.Minute}:{currentTime.Second}.{currentTime.Millisecond} WndProc: {m.Msg} ==> {(WindowsMessage)m.Msg}");
    Console.WriteLine($"#Number of touches: {GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.MAXIMUMTOUCHES)}.");
    Console.WriteLine($"#TabletMode: {GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.TABLETPC)}.");

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Connecting a touch device generates multiple (4-5) `DEVICECHANGE` messages as well as mixed results for `number of touches` ranging from all 0, all 1 or in the best case a mix with the last one a 10. `Tabletmode` is either off or in the best case on. Often times before `number of touches` is greater then 0. It just seems all semi random and unreliable.

Example output:

```
#36.810 WndProc: 537 ==> DEVICECHANGE
#Number of touches: 0.
#TabletMode: 0.
#36.827 WndProc: 537 ==> DEVICECHANGE
#Number of touches: 0.
#TabletMode: 0.
#36.866 WndProc: 537 ==> DEVICECHANGE
#Number of touches: 0.
#TabletMode: 0.
#36.876 WndProc: 537 ==> DEVICECHANGE
#Number of touches: 0.
#TabletMode: 0.
#36.976 WndProc: 712 ==> 712
#Number of touches: 0.
#TabletMode: 0.
```

Fortunatly, everytime I plug and unplug the touch device I also get message `0x02c8 (712)` and `0x02c9 (713)`. This feels like some kind of `touch device connected` and `touch device disconnected` messages, but the `windows message` enum doesn't have these messages. Looking around, I can't actually find a `windows message` list that has them. I even looked in my `WinUser.h` files.

So per the title, does anyone know what these windows messages are?

Comment: A [quick google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows+message+0x02c8) shows they are `WM_TABLET_FIRST+9` and `WM_TABLET_FIRST+10`.

Comment: @GSerg with that search I found `WM_POINTERDEVICEADDED = 0x02c8` and `WM_POINTERDEVICEDELETED = 0x02c9` (https://github.com/dapplo/Dapplo.Windows/blob/master/src/Dapplo.Windows.Messages/WindowsMessages.cs)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Interesting, that seems to confirm my suspicion!

Comment: After reading https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3100913/wpf-touch-input-stops-working it seems this is the link you're looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317339(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I am not sure I want to understand the "all over the placeness" if these header files (winuser.h/tpcshrd.h)... Anyway, want to put this as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: I don't want to take credit for @GSerg's google-fu and just being curious :P You could answer your own question saying your suspicion was correct, and accept that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion was correct, from tpcshrd.h:

```
#define WM_TABLET_DEFBASE                    0x02C0
#define WM_TABLET_MAXOFFSET                  0x20
#define WM_TABLET_ADDED                      (WM_TABLET_DEFBASE + 8)
#define WM_TABLET_DELETED                    (WM_TABLET_DEFBASE + 9)
#define WM_TABLET_FLICK                      (WM_TABLET_DEFBASE + 11)
#define WM_TABLET_QUERYSYSTEMGESTURESTATUS   (WM_TABLET_DEFBASE + 12)
```